# Error while connecting to oracle DB from a python code in java (cx_Oracle)

Tags: java, python, oracle, intellij-idea

I'm trying to run a python script from java code in order to connect to an Oracle DB (using `cx_oracle`). I'm coding in intellij IDEA 14. When I run my python code alone, everything is ok, but when I run my python code from my java code, I recieve an Error:

```
File "D:\New folder\fuckedtest\src\Oracle\connection.py", line 6, in <module>
    import cx_Oracle
  File "__pyclasspath__/cx_Oracle/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "__pyclasspath__/cx_Oracle/datetime.py", line 11, in <module>
ImportError: No module named cx_Oracle._BASEVARTYPE
```

this is my code in java:

```
   public void con(){


    PythonInterpreter pythonInterpreter = new PythonInterpreter();
    pythonInterpreter.execfile("D:\\New folder\\fuckedtest\\src\\Oracle\\connection.py");
    PyObject ansd = pythonInterpreter.eval("testcx()");
    System.out.println(ansd.toString());

}
```

and this is my python code:

```
    def testcx():
 import cx_Oracle

 connection = cx_Oracle.Connection("system/Admin1234@127.0.0.1/orcl")
 cursor = connection.cursor()
```

I should say that I've run many python scripts from java code and it worked fine. I don't know what is wrong here and why it can't import `cx_Oracle` in this method.

Comment: From the comments of other cx_Oracle questions there seem to be some dependencies both on your oracle client as well as the dlls matching your architecture. But standalone this script runs and connects to oracle? Do you run 32bit java and 64bit python or vice versa?

Comment: thanks Jan for reply. yeah this script runs and connect to oracle when I run it standalone whether on python IDLE or on intellij python IDLE. but when I call it from my java code I get the Error. Both of them are 64 bit. My JDK is 64 bit and I use python 3.4.4 64bit as python SDK. I got cx_Oracle from sourceforge and installed it on my python.

Comment: when I run the python script from java, intellij reads cx_Oracle.pyd file and breaks it to many files (methods). But it doesn't create the file (method) named _BASEVARTYPE and I think maybe this is the problem. But I don't know the solution in this case too. @Jan