# calling python method through java ProcessBuilder()

Tags: java, python

How can I call a method in a Python file using `ProcessBuilder` in java? My Python file has a class and three methods. Also, how can I set my python method params from ProcessBuilder?

Here is my **Java code**:

```
public void con3(){
    try {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Python34\\python.exe", "D:\\New folder\\test\\src\\NewCodes\\pickel4output.py","may","vay");
        Process p = pb.start();
        System.out.println(p);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line = "";
        System.out.println("Running Python starts: " + line);
        int exitCode = p.waitFor();
        System.out.println("Exit Code : "+exitCode);
        line = in.readLine();
        System.out.println("First Line: " + line);
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null){
            System.out.println("Python Output: " + line);
        }
    }
}
```

This is a part of my **Python code**:

```
import pickle
class Test(object):

def pic(self,var1,var2):
    print(var1)
    print(var2)
    dic={}
    f=open('D:\\New folder\\test\\src\\NewCodes\\dicfile.pck','rb')
    dic=pickle.load(f)
    for record in range(4):
        dic=pickle.load(f)
        print(dic)
        dic.clear()

    f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think reading the executable (a series of binary numbers) will do any good. Also, The class java.lang.ProcessBuilder, in Java 1.5, is used to create operating system processe. Instead you should use the jython API: http://www.jython.org/javadoc/org/python/util/PythonInterpreter.html

Particularly: PyInstance and PythonInterpreter;

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  But you know At first I was using jython. But I've faced some problems with jython.  Jython has problem with python scripts that import cpython modules (i.e cx_Oracle). Look at this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34578017/error-while-connecting-to-oracle-db-from-a-python-code-in-java-cx-oracle

Comment: Do you have any suggestion about the problem of importing cx_Oracle? Also I don't know about Pyinstance... What is it? @Mattsap

Comment: PyInstance just allows you to create instances of a python class. I don't have any experience with cs_Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can't call a Python function from a ProcessBuilder, but you can create a Python program which calls a function from your Python module. And than you can run it from a ProcessBuilder as a command:

```
python -c 'from pickel4output import pic; pic()'
```

However, take into attention that since your `pic` function expects some parameters, you have to create a python code which reads these parameters from a file or a command line and then run the function.